# Categorize cells by keywords

Tags: excel-2010

I am not certain if excel can do this but I am trying to simplify the data dump that I get from twitter.

Basically what I would like to do is this:

If the tweet (in Column A) contains apple OR orange OR pear then it can be classified (in Column B) as "fruit" BUT if it has carrot OR squash OR lettuce it will be classified as "vegetable". If it has none of these then can be classified as "none"

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer your question, that is possible using a formula. You can use array constants or you can use a range or named range to contain the list you are trying to find match from the string in Column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is using *array constant* and *range*.

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH({"apple","orange","pear"},A1)),0,1))>0,"Fruit",IF(SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH({"carrot","squash","lettuce"},A1)),0,1))>0,"Vegetable","None"))`

Now for example, both fruit and vegetable are present in a string, it will always test for fruit first since that is the way the formula was arranged. (e.g. "more apple on salad than lettuce" will return "Fruit").
You can also use a range that contains your list instead of the array constant.
For example, you can put your fruit list in Column C (C1:C3) and your vegetable list in Column D (D1:D3).
 Your formula would then be:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(C$1:C$3,A1)),0,1))>0,"Fruit",IF(SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D$1:D$3,A1)),0,1))>0,"Vegetable","None"))`

But you need to enter it as *Array Formula* using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Same results and rule apply when both fruit and vegetable appear on a string. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Try this formula

```
=IF(
    OR(
       NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("apple",A1))),
       NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("pear",A1))),
       NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("orange",A1)))
    ),
    "fruit",
    IF(
       OR(
          NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("carrot",A1))),
          NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("squash",A1))),
          NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("lettuce",A1)))
      ),
      "veggie",
      "none"
  )
)
```